# How to get the prototype name inside the function itself?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm creating a function for `Element` and I couldn't find a proper way to get the prototype name itself into it, that's the way I tried, but I don't think it's the most appropriate way, there is some more conventional way to to get the name inside the prototype itself?

```
Element.prototype.getCssStyle = function getCssStyle(stylePropertyName) {
    var protoName = Element.getCssStyle.name;
 
    return protoName;
}
```

Comment: What is a "prototype name"? What is `Elem_` meant to be in your example? What do you mean the example to do?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It's the name of the function itself.

Comment: `"getCssStyle"`? That has nothing to do with prototypes. (Also, what do you want it for?)

Comment: This looks like you're trying to reinvent [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

Comment: @Andy Yes, I am creating a prototype for `Element` to get the property values ​​from `Css`, if the user doesn't enter a property name I will return an error to him and also the name of the prototype itself that caused the error , everything works fine, but I would like to know if there is a correct way to get the prototype name itself inside itself, the name of the created function itself.

Comment: *"if the user doesn't enter a property name I will return an error to him and also the name of the prototype itself that caused the error"* Just throw an error, the JavaScript engine will provide the stack trace saying where the error occurred.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry, I corrected the code

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm not interested in throwing a bug itself, but just a `console. warn` anyway, thanks for the help

Comment: An error, not a "bug." But that's fine, if you just want to issue a warning I've shown how to get the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to get the string "getCssStyle"`within the`getCssStyle`function, you'd do that by using`getCssStyle.name`:

```js
Element.prototype.getCssStyle = function getCssStyle(stylePropertyName) {
    var functionName = getCssStyle.name;
 
    return functionName;
}
console.log(document.createElement("div").getCssStyle());
```

The name of a function provides an in-scope identifier within the function that refers to the function, and functions have a `name` property giving their name.

Or get it from the same place you assigned it, `Element.prototype.getCssStyle`:

```js
Element.prototype.getCssStyle = function getCssStyle(stylePropertyName) {
    var functionName = Element.prototype.getCssStyle.name;
 
    return functionName;
}
console.log(document.createElement("div").getCssStyle());
```

Note that in both cases, this is the name of the *function*, not necessarily the property you assign it to.

---

Side note: I **strongly** recommend not creating methods on built-in prototypes via direct assignment. It creates enumerable properties on the prototypes, which can mess up naively-written code.

It's generally best not to add to built-in prototypes at all (and certainly not in *library* code), but it can be okay-ish in your own app or page code. To do it, use `Object.defineProperty`

```js
Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, "getCssStyle", {
    value: function getCssStyle(stylePropertyName) {
        var functionName = getCssStyle.name;
 
        return functionName;
    },
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
});
console.log(document.createElement("div").getCssStyle());
```

The `enumerable` flag is false by default (all three flags are), but I've included it above for emphasis.

Comment: @TJCrowder Quality content friend, as I'm a little time with javascript I didn't understand 100% but I'm incredibly astonished with the explanation, powerfully didactic. What do you mean by `built-in prototypes` and `direct assignment` ?. Is like this: `Element.directAssignment = function () {
    return 'Hello, i'm direct assignment';
}`, direct assignment to built-in prototypes is it?

Comment: @Chris - :-) Thanks. Yes, sorry, `Element.prototype.getCssStyle = someFunction` is direct assignment. Built-in prototypes are the prototypes of built-in objects in the environment like `Object`, `Array`, `Date` (from JavaScript) and `Element`, `HTMLElement`, `NodeList`, etc. (from the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model)).

Comment: @TJCrowder Perfect, now I really understand, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

[arguments.callee](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee) ref to the function itself.

```js
Element.prototype.getCssStyle = function getCssStyle(stylePropertyName) {
    var protoName = arguments.callee.name;

    return protoName;
}
```

Comment: `arguments.callee` is deprecated, fails in strict mode, and should never be used in modern code.